# JPA2 Should I prefer critieria queries to JPQL?

Tags: jpa-2.0, criteria-api

So I have three models.. a Crag has one or more CragLocations and each CragLocation has a Location. I can query for a certain subset of crags using

```
public List<Crag> getCragsWithGridRef() {
        /**
         * we want to query select c.* from crag c join CragLocation cl on c.id
         * = cl.cragId join Location l on cl.locationId = l.id where
         * len(l.gridReference)>1
         */
        TypedQuery<Crag> query = 
                em.createQuery(
                        "SELECT c FROM Crag c JOIN c.CragLocations cl JOIN cl.location l where LENGTH(l.gridReference) > 1",
                        Crag.class);
        return query.getResultList();
    }
```

I'm largely querying this way because my brain can't handle criteria queries. I struggle to parse the meaning when I'm looking at them.

So is there a performance or maintainability (or other) reason to prefer criteria queries and if so how would you express this query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no reason to prefer criteria queries over JPQL ones, especially if you consider JPQL queries easy to understand and thus to maintain, and criteria queries hard to understand and maintain (which I agree with).

Criteria queries, if you use the auto-generated metamodel, are hard to write, but once written, you can be sure that there is no syntax error. That doesn't mean that the query does what it's supposed to do, though. So in any case, you should unit-test the queries. If you have unit test covering the queries, then use what you find the most readable and maintainable. Even if there was a performance difference generating the underlying SQL query, this difference would be negligible compared to the cost of actually executing the query.

I use Criteria queries only in those two situations (and not even always):

1. the query is dynamically composed from a set of optional search criteria
2. There are many similar queries sharing a common part, and I want to avoid repeating this common part in each and every query. Using a criteria allows putting the common parts in a reusable method.

Comment: One more thing. Once you get the hang of writing Criteria queries you will very occasionally find that the generated sequel will be something you never would have thought of ... but it works. That is pretty cool.